# Effective range of a laser propelled solar sail

Tags: spacecraft, probe, solar-sail, long-duration, breakthrough-starshot

The ongoing Breakthrough Starshot program proposes the use of high powered lasers on Earth to be aimed at a solar sail with the intention of propelling it to the star Alpha Centauri.

To be more specific, just how far could we effectively propel the craft, and maintain a connection for downloading information.

Is it realistic?

Comment: "Realistic" covers a spectrum of possibilities from "doesn't break any known laws of physics" to "could be done tomorrow to a fairly predictable cost and timescale".  From what I can see, Breakthrough Starshot is very much closer to the former than the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How far could we effectively propel the craft?**

For space travel, "how far" isn't a very good question to determine the difficulty of space travel. Instead, a much better metric is the delta-v, or change in velocity.

And to answer that question, [their website says](http://breakthroughinitiatives.org/about) that tiny unmanned probes would be able to be accelerated to about 15-20% the speed of light.

**How far could we maintain a connection for downloading information?**

The current leading idea of how to manage these communications is through [optical laser communications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_communication_in_space).

This will be tested over interplanetary distances for the first time on [the Psyche probe](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=6967), which launches in a few years; however, scientists are confident that they will be able to use these to communicate to all nearby stars with ease. We will, of course, have a better idea of what the limits are in a few years time, after we've used them over longer distances and see them in action more.

Comment: Thank you, forgot about delta-v. Guess that means that now we only have to get past the technological hurdles that are in our way.

Comment: Well, "only" is a bit of an understatement, as those are some pretty large technological hurdles, but yes.